# SQL: How to sum values into categories in ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

How to sum values into categories in ssms?

```
SELECT
,[CustomerName]
,[ItemRelation]
,[SaleCount]
,[DocumentNum]
,[DocumentYear]
,[IsPromo]

FROM mytable
```

The fields

```
,[CustomerName
,[ItemRelation]
,[DocumentNum]
,[DocumentYear]
```

are stratified categories
for example, `"the shop of horns and hoofs" - "111" - "37" - "2018year"`.
`[SaleCount]` number of sales.
What is the difficulty.
For each such stratum there is data on the stock [IsPromo] (0-no stock, 1 is a stock)
the data sample is truncated, just an example

```
[ItemRelation]  [SaleCount] IsPromo ,[DocumentNum]  [DocumentYear]
11202        8,85947691     0      137                   2018
11202   9,450108704 0   137 2018
11202   12,40326767 1   137 2018
11202   25,98779894 1   137 2018
11202   63,19760196 1   137 2018
11203   8,85947691  0   138 2018
11203   9,450108704 0   138 2018
11203   12,40326767 1   138 2018
```

we see that for stratum

```
[ItemRelation], [DocumentNum] [DocumentYear]
11202              137              2018
```

3 ones and two zero by ispromo

and 
by stratum

```
[ItemRelation], [DocumentNum] [DocumentYear]
11203            138            2018
```

here
2 ones and one zero

How can I write a query that returns only those "stratum" in which the `ones` for ispromo occur from 2 to 4 times inclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can return all matching records of each stratum by summing `IsPromo` over each stratum and then retaining only records having a sum between 2 and 4 inclusive.

```
SELECT [ItemRelation], [DocumentNum], [DocumentYear]  -- and maybe other columns
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        SUM(CAST(IsPromo AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum,
            DocumentYear) promo_sum
    FROM mytable
) t
WHERE t.promo_sum BETWEEN 2 AND 4;
```

Note: If you really wanted see each matching stratum only once, then we could have used a `GROUP BY` query instead.  But, you can still easily modify the above query to `SELECT DISTINCT` to get this result.

Comment: Tim, i have one question SELECT CustomerName, ItemRelation, SaleCount,
DocumentNum, DocumentYear, IsPromo, CustomerType  -- and maybe other columns
FROM
(
  SELECT *,
  SUM(IsPromo) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName,ItemRelation, DocumentNum,
  DocumentYear) promo_sum
  FROM  [Action].[dbo].[promo_data]
) t
  WHERE t.promo_sum BETWEEN 2 AND 4;  the error  Message 8117, level 16, state 1, line 7
The data type of the bit operand is not valid for the sum operator. What's wrong

Comment: i think it because ispromo is bit type. How to convert it in int type?

Comment: @varimax Use `CAST(IsPromo AS INT)` to treat it as integer.

Comment: Tim, you are the great. Can You help me in similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837090/sql-how-to-sort-values-into-categories-in-ssms

Answer (score 1):

You could try something among the lines:

```
select [ItemRelation] , [SaleCount],[DocumentNum]  [DocumentYear]
from mytable
group by IsPromo
having IsPromo = 1 and count(IsPromo)>=2 and count(IsPromo)>=4
```