# SQL: How to sort values into categories in ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

i create the query

```
SELECT Dt, CustomerName, ItemRelation, SaleCount, 
              DocumentNum, DocumentYear, IsPromo, CustomerType
              FROM [dbo].[promo_data]  where [CustomerType]='XY'
```

there is data on the stock [IsPromo] (0-no stock, 1 is a stock) 
how can i select only these obs XY of CustomerType 
which have only one value 1 for the action category = 1

simple example

```
[ItemRelation]  [SaleCount] IsPromo ,[DocumentNum]  [DocumentYear]
11203   8,85947691  0   138 2018
11203   9,450108704 0   138 2018
11203   12,40326767 1   138 2018
11202   8,85947691  0   137 2018
11202   9,450108704 0   137 2018
11202   12,40326767 1   137 2018
11202   25,98779894 1   137 2018
11202   63,19760196 1   137 2018
```

i must select

```
11203       1   138 2018
```

because

```
11202       137 2018
```

has two ones

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, IsPromo
FROM [dbo].[promo_data]
WHERE CustomerType = 'XY' AND IsPromo = 1
GROUP BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, IsPromo
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

EDIT:

To retrieve all columns, use window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT pd.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, IsPromo) as cnt
      FROM [dbo].[promo_data] pd
      WHERE CustomerType = 'XY' AND IsPromo = 1
     ) pd
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Can you really group by SaleCount in this case?

Comment: @JanneP . . . The OP didn't request sales count, so it should not be in the query at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,  the SaleCount must be returned in query. How to do it not aggregating it into GROUP BY

Comment: @varimax check my answer based on Gordon Linoff's original for returning additional columns

Comment: @varimax . . . You sample results do not suggest that you want that in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gordon's answer, if you want to select additional fields not used in grouping, you could do a self-join with a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT pd.Dt, pd.CustomerName, pd.ItemRelation, pd.SaleCount, 
              pd.DocumentNum, pd.DocumentYear, pd.IsPromo, pd.CustomerType 
FROM [dbo].[promo_data] pd
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, IsPromo
  FROM [dbo].[promo_data]
  WHERE CustomerType = 'XY' AND IsPromo = 1
  GROUP BY ItemRelation, DocumentNum, DocumentYear, IsPromo
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) grouped
ON pd.ItemRelation = grouped.ItemRelation
AND pd.DocumentNum = grouped.DocumentNum
AND pd.DocumentYear = grouped.DocumentYear
AND pd.IsPromo = grouped.IsPromo
```